# How shoud i verify the downloaded image in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

```html
<img id="imgCoverImage" class="imgCoverImg" alt="cover image"src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51IH3D6kpSL._SL160_.jpg">
```

I have downloaded a cover image of book to my web page. I want to verify that image using Selenium IDE. i tried verifyElementPresent command but its not working for me.

Comment: are you trying to do an image comparison

Comment: no.. i have downloaded it and now i want to verify if the image is present or not

Comment: there was no image at the begging . after download i need to verify that downloaded image

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Present -- its just check tag presence, but not presence of the image inside of it.
If you will check Displayed -- its just check tag visibility, but not presence of the image inside of it.
If you will check src attribute presence -- its just check that src is exist, but doesn't check that image was loaded.

You can save image to some folder and check its size. If size larger than 40kb (as example) -- its exist and large enough. 
In another case selenium will check image tag, but not the image.
And delete the image after this.

Maybe this is bad way, but this will work.